# jQuery id filter works in MSIE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, opera

I'm trying to use the .each() function of JQuery on a body load to assign functionality to different areas in an image-map. It works fine in MSIE but fails completely in any other browser. If I hardcode the javascript function and call it using:

```
href="javascript:cInfo(mapHeadG)"
```

as an attribute for each area it works in all browsers so I know it's not the code itself. I am guessing it has to be the filter I'm using. Any suggestions would be helpful!

Here is the image map element:

```
<map id="mMap1" name="mMap1">
    <area coords="44, 13, 116, 14, 123, 21, 36, 21" 
          shape="poly" alt="" id="mapHeadG" class="mLink" />
    <area coords="37, 66, 113, 65, 117, 73, 34, 76" 
          shape="poly" alt="" id="mapNeckG" />
    <area coords="8, 83, 141, 79, 144, 88, 126, 97, 9, 96, 2, 92" 
          shape="poly" alt="" id="mapShoulderG" />
</map>
```

Here is the JQuery I use to assign the functionality:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('*[id*=map]:visible').each(function () {
            var sec = $(this).attr('id');
            alert(sec);
            $(this).hover(function () {
                //Do something here.
            }, function () {
                //Do something here.
            });
            $(this).click(function () {
                //Do something else here
            })
        });
    });
```

*(The sec variable is just a test to see if I am getting any information, this fires in MSIE but not in the other browsers)*

You will see the `alert(sec)` line in the javascript, this is how I know the function is working in MSIE but not in the others, well this and the fact that when I click the mapped areas in MSIE this works but fails in the others.

Like I said before, I am almost positive it has to do with the filter itself, but I can't seem to find it. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I completely forgot something in the code (deleted it not thinking, sorry). As you can see, the areas do not have an href. The line missing in the .each function is:

`$(this).attr('href','#');`

It makes the area selectable. Even if I add it to the area as an attribute still doesnt work.

Comment: Since `map` tags merely define hit-points for images, and are therefore abstract themselves, what precisely are you trying to do? Are you sure you shouldn't be pointing your code to the images, rather than the maps?

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your suggestions, they actually helped me figure it out. It was the :visible that was stopping the other browsers. Using the following:

    $('#Map1' area).each()

or in my case since I have more than one map:

    $(*[id*=mMap] area).each()

allows the functionality to be assigned to each image map area.

Appreciate your tips, thanks again.

Comment: @Utkanos. There are two images on the page representing well-formed and malformed skeletons (medical). Areas of each image representing "problem" points are clickable, and when they are clicked, in-depth information is presented. Currently each image has 9 points scattered across each, and the customer will most likely add more. Since they are scattered "randomly" (i.e., the elbow, which may be bent or straightened, elevated or relaxed, etc.) the best way to capture hovers and clicks is with an imagemap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to both of you for your suggestions (including the one that disappeared), they actually helped me figure it out. It was the :visible that was stopping the other browsers. Using the following:

```
$('#Map1' area).each()
```

or in my case since I have more than one map

```
$(*[id*=mMap] area).each()
```

allows the functionality to be assigned to each image map area.

Appreciate your tips, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a strange and labor intensive way to do targeting. Have you tried this instead:

```
$('#mMap1 area:visible').each(function () {
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I changed it as recommended, fires as expected in MSIE but still won't fire in the others. I hardcoded the href="#" into each area to make sure they were clickable but nada.